# Track causality in message queue

Tags: parallel-processing, architecture, rabbitmq, queue, amqp

I'm working on a system where I have to process multiple messages but keep partial order of these messages. I have RabbitMQ queue with messages of two types: item create and item update.

Consider we have queue with 6 messages:

```
CREATE1 CREATE2 UPDATE1 UPDATE2 UPDATE1 UPDATE1
```

- If I process them one by one, then it's completely fine, but it's very slow, because I have lots of messages
- If I read them into some buffer, then I can process them in parallel, but I can process `UPDATE1` for first item which wasn't created yet. The worse, the last update may be processed before previous one and thus erase latest item state

I can create some extra field in the message or put it in the queue with some extra header, e.g. `MESSAGE_ID:10` to make sure that all messages for one item have the same `MESSAGE_ID`. The problem is that I don't know what to do with it.

How can I read from the queue multiple items at once without breaking causality between messages?

---

The pseudocode that I imagine for this task could be:

```
const prefetchItemsCount = 20
let buffer = new Message[prefetchItemsCount]
let set = new Set()
foreach item in queue
    if !set.Contains(item.MessageId)
         set.Add(item.MessageId)
         buffer.Add(item)
         if set.Count == buffer.Count
             break
return buffer
```

So in our example it will return following sequences of items:

```
CREATE1 CREATE2
UPDATE1 UPDATE2
UPDATE1
UPDATE1
```

Which makes it almost twice as faster

Answer (score 1):

> *How can I **read** from the queue multiple items **at once** without breaking **causality** between messages?*

Nice case, indeed.

If indeed performed in the desired manner, the TimeDOMAIN singularity of "**at once**" goes principally against **a hidden morphology of** what was expressed as "**causality**".

Given together with a QUEUE-ingress side, which is by definition a pure-**`[SERIAL]`** ( nothing may happen at once, just a pure one-goes-after-another, even if a "just"-`[CONCURENT]` scheduling may get exposed to external agents, the internal QUEUE-management conforms to a pure sequential ordering of messages internal flow and delivery ( also ref. to time-stamping, persistence and other artefacts thereof ) ).

**Causality** also means some **`cause -> effect`** ordering of events, both in the abstracted causality sense of the relation and also in the flow of real time of how thing indeed do happen, so practically an anti-pattern to the "**at once**".

Last, but not least, the **Causality** also has to handle an additional paradigm, the **latency** between the **`cause ->`** side and the **`-> effect`** side of the ( often **F**inite-**S**tate-**A**utomata, typically having much richer state-space than a just `{ 0 -> CREATE -> UPDATE [ -> UPDATE [...] ] -> }` ) series of events.

Result?

While one may "read" using some degree of `[CONCURRENT]`-scheduling of processes, the FSA / Causality conditions principally avoid moving anywhere out of the principal pure-**`[SERIAL]`** post-processing of event-messages delivered.

More reguirements on this come, if the messaging framework is broker-less and without guarranteed robustness against lost messages / messages ordering / messages authenticity / messages content.

There the Devils start to dance against your attempts to build a consistent, distributed transaction processing robust, distributed FSA :o)

Comment: Please, see edit. I added what I imagine while I want to prefetch in parallel, but without breaking causality.